# NodeJS the devDependencies of my dependencies/devDependencies are not being installed or listed

Tags: node.js, dependencies

In my project the `devDependencies` of my `dependencies`, or indeed my `devDependencies`, are not being installed when I run

> npm install

or

> npm install --include=dev

In many ways this seems sensible. But one of the dependencies, maybe incorrectly, fails when a `devDependency` is not available.

Is this meant to work? `npm` **does install** the sub `dependencies` it just seems to ignore the `devDependencies`.

An example of one of my dependenices `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test-helper-chai",
  "version": "1.0.11",
  "description": "chai extended with specific assertions",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "devMain": "src/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "sinon": "^9.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "check-error": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn build:src",
    "build:src": "build -dest \"./dist\" -src \"./src\" -js -ts -maps",
    "test": "yarn test:style && yarn test:unit && yarn test:integration && yarn test:browser",
    "test:browser": "test --integration --unit --runner karma",
    "test:integration": "test --integration --runner mocha",
    "test:style": "eslint ./src/**/*.*",
    "test:unit": "test --unit --runner jest"
  }
}
```

Here `chai` is not being installed but `check-error` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

When you run `npm install` in the same directory as a package.json file, npm will install both devDependencies and dependencies for that package.json. It's presumed that package.json is the package under development.

Nested dependencies work differently. Only the regular dependencies of nested dependencies will get installed. This is to cut down on bloat. Imagine if every package shipped all of their build tools, development packages, and linters along with their production code!

It's worth keeping in mind for the package you develop. If a dependency is needed for the production package to run, you should install it in `dependencies`. If it's only needed for build/development, it should go in devDependencies.

Comment: This sounds correct to me. Is there any official documentation on this behaviour?

Comment: It's not as explicit as I'd like, but devDependencies mentions it in passing: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#devdependencies